# Get input characters typed by the user(WINAPI, user32.dll)

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, user32

I need to get an input point (caret position, window/control) that is focused. My application/service needs to detect when the user starts typing and then replace the characters that were typed with predetermined values. The trick is that I don't know where the user wants to type(I don't want to limit this to several applications).

I think that I know how to get/replace the text using:

```
[DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wparam, StringBuilder text);
```

How do I get the control that is focused? How do I know from where to get the text and where to send the replacement?

I am doing this in C#, WPF.

Thank you!

Comment: How are you getting the keystrokes? If you are using an event handler, the RoutedEventArgs has a property called 'OriginalSource'.  This property gets the original reporting source as determined by pure hit testing, before any possible Source adjustment by a parent class.  This will indicate which control the end user was entering text into.  You would then query this control for its Text property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am presuming that since you have tagged your question as WinAPI your are trying to intercept keystrokes from another application as in Keyboard [Hooking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959.aspx). Take a look at these Links:

- [Intercepting and Blocking Keystrokes](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/microsoft/Win32-Kernel/31799700/intercepting-and-blocking-keystrokes.aspx)
- [How do I set a low level mouse hook and keyboard hook in C#?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/74f3d7b1-afa3-4a38-8132-59c754ad1ae7)
- [How to set a Windows hook in Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804)
- [A Simple C# Global Low Level Keyboard Hook](http://A%20Simple%20C#%20Global%20Low%20Level%20Keyboard%20Hook)

Comment: That us exactly what I'm trying to do. I am trying to intercept them and then return something else to the same application/control. Thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to emulate keyboard activity, you can use [`keybd_event`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/keybd_event.html) or [`SendInput`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendInput.html).  These automatically deliver the keypresses to the window with focus, so you don't have to detect it yourself.